# How to know whether the method inside a method has been called or not in XCTest

Tags: ios, objective-c, xctest

How can I verify that a method inside a method has been called or not in XCTest framework using Xcode 7.

A sample method which I want to figure out is

```
-(void)setupMapAria {
//some code
[self setUpLocation:[UserDetails currentLocation]];
//some code.
}
```

Here how can I check or write unit test case that `setUpLocation` has been  called or not.(Note this method does not return anything).

Comment: The easiest way to test this is to use a mock.

Comment: will mock support in xcode 7.2 ? how to do that. i thought it is in older verstions of xcode.

Comment: I am new to unit testing. if possible give me the link a for xcode 7.2 documentation link with OCMock frame work

Comment: The website of OCMock has everything you need to know.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you don't want to test that `setUpLocation` has been called. A better test, if possible, is to test for the **desired results** of that method, given specific locations.

In which case, the challenge is to substitute test input in place of `[UserDetails currentLocation]` so that you can control the test. We want to inject the dependency.

There are various forms of [Dependency Injection](https://www.objc.io/issues/15-testing/dependency-injection/). In your example, the extra challenge is that in the production code, `setupMapAria` should get a *fresh instance* of the current location every time.

A simple way to do that is with **method injection**. We can create a new method:

```
-(void)setupMapAriaWithLocation:(UserLocation *)location;
```

Testing that is much easier! Just pass in whatever you need. Tests can then query the state of whatever `setUpLocation:` does.

As for `setupMapAria`, you now have a choice. You can keep it, having it simply call `setupMapAriaWithLocation:`. Or you can eliminate it, and change the caller to pass in the current location. …You may even discover your program is more flexible as a result, by letting you handle locations other than the current location. (For example, user's location at different points in time.)